# how to Extract Urls from XML Sitemap URL using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php
function extractSitemapUrls($sitemapUrl) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($sitemapUrl);

    if ($xml === false) {
        die('Error loading XML');
    }

    $urls = [];

    foreach ($xml->url as $url) {
        $urls[] = (string)$url->loc;
    }

    return $urls;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Get the sitemap URL from the form
    $sitemapUrl = $_POST['sitemap_url'];

    if (filter_var($sitemapUrl, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        // Extract URLs from the sitemap
        $urls = extractSitemapUrls($sitemapUrl);

        // Output the extracted URLs
        echo "<h2>Extracted URLs:</h2>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            echo "<li>$url</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

It uses the simplexml_load_file function to load the XML content from the provided URL into a SimpleXML object.

The PHP script checks if the form has been submitted using $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'.
If the form is submitted, it retrieves the sitemap URL from $_POST['sitemap_url'].
It then validates the URL using filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL to ensure it is a valid URL.
If the URL is valid, it calls the extractSitemapUrls function to get the URLs from the sitemap and displays them.

i am trying to make a similar page like [XML Sitemap URL Extractor](https://miniimg.com/sitemap-url-extractor/). the php code is not exacting.

Comment: Anything not working with the given code? How is this problem related to JS or HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Examine the XML structure. The root `$xml` contains an array `sitemap` with each element having the `loc` property.

[image: Example Sitemap Structure]

*Examined with PHPStorm and XDebug.*

```
$sitemapUrl = 'https://www.google.com/sitemap.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($sitemapUrl);

if ($xml === false) {
    die('Error loading XML');
}

$urls = [];

foreach ($xml->sitemap as $url) {
    $urls[] = (string)$url->loc;
}

var_dump($urls);
```